# How to get 'Windows 10' user first & last name with offline DC

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, offline, domaincontroller

How to get user first name and last name in Windows 10 without connection to domain for specified (or at worst case logged in) account name? Machine was at least once connected to Domain Controller (Laptop).

I tried using UserPrincipal (which obviously throws PrincipalException with LDAPException inside). Also searched many threads (so far all are about case with DC connected).

Comment: which user you want to get ?

Comment: Domain user. Possibly with given account name (SamAccountName). In worst case scenario currently logged in would do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static void GetUsers()  
{  
     SelectQuery sQuery = new SelectQuery(“Win32_UserAccount”,“Domain=’yourdomain’”);  

     try  
     {  
            ManagementObjectSearcher mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sQuery);  

            Console.WriteLine(“User Accounts\n”);  

            foreach (ManagementObject mObject in mSearcher.Get())  
            {  
                // Console.WriteLine(mObject[“Name”]);  
                // your logic
            }  
      }  
      catch (Exception ex)  
      {  
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);  
      }  


 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it works just as PrincipalContext. 

If DC is avaivable everything is ok. Without DC results are empty. Without condition parameter and connection to DC results are same like from PrincipalContext with ContextType=Machine.